# Extending magento core controller but not working

Tags: php, magento, module, controller

I am extending the magento core controller but it can't working. it cannot display any error. I have creating a module for it. the module is shown at the back-end in system/configuration/advanced . I have two files controller and etc.
Controller/AccountController.php:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
//we need to add this one since Magento wont recognize it automatically

class Inchoo_Coreextended_Frontend_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{//here, you extended the core controller with our
public function indexAction()
{
parent::indexAction();
//you can always use default functionality
}
public function myactionAction()
{
//my code
//you can write your own methods / actions
}
public function mymethod()
{
//my code
//you can write your own methods
}
public function loginAction()
{
    echo "har har mahadev";
//finally you can write your code that will rewrite the whole core method
//and you can call for your own methods, as you have full control over core controller
}
}
```

and etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Coreextended>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Inchoo_Coreextended before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">
                            Inchoo_Coreextended_Frontend_Customer_AccountController
                        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

when I am trying to login than it display core login file not my module login  and also can't shown any error and the value from my module.
so please suggest me, what can i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make this changes and it will fix the problem

```
  <config>
        <modules>
            <Inchoo_Coreextended>
                <active>true</active>
                <codepool>local</codepool>
            </Inchoo_Coreextended>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

after

> ```
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Inchoo_Coreextended>
>             <active>true</active>
>             <codePool>local</codePool>
>         </Inchoo_Coreextended>
>     </modules>
> </config>
> ```

codepool should be codePool

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, this xml section:

```
<Inchoo_Coreextended before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">
    Inchoo_Coreextended_Frontend_Customer_AccountController
</Inchoo_Coreextended>
```

Should be

```
<Inchoo_Coreextended before="Mage_Customer">Inchoo_Coreextended</Inchoo_Coreextended>
```

Put it on one line, because Magento does not trim the xml nodes.

Then your class should be placed in

`app/code/local/Inchoo/Coreextended/controllers/AccountController.php` and it should be named `Inchoo_Coreextended_AccountController`.

The rest seams to be ok.

Comment: Hi Marius,
I have made these changes, but it still can't working.
now directory path is 
app/code/local/Inchoo/Coreextended/controllers/AccountController.php

Comment: i am also having the same issue please suggest other ideas

Comment: did you add the module declaration file in `app/etc/modules`? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes, I have clear the cache and the module is appearing in the admin.

Comment: @marius  i believe it is not getting the accountcontroler.php file even because i have try to put syntax error in the beginning of file  but still there is no effect

Comment: surely there is some problem in config.xml  please suggest how can i fix this

Comment: also there is no effect of any syntax error in config,ml file so it can also be the possibility of that it is not getting config dile also  please suggest what can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_Coreextended>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Inchoo_Coreextended before="Mage_Customer">
                            Inchoo_Coreextended_AccountController
                        </Inchoo_Coreextended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and in your module make directory structure as

```
Inchoo
  /Coreextended
   /controllers
    /AccountController.php
```

and in the file make the class as

```
class Inchoo_Coreextended_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
```

hope it helps!